# Eureka server not accessible for traditional war deployment In Docker

Tags: tomcat, gradle, docker, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Eureka boot gradle project [here](https://github.com/abhijitsarkar/java-ee/tree/master/discovery-service). Works fine when I run `bootRun`, Eureka binds to port 8080 on localhost, accessible from browser, everyone happy. When started as a Docker container, the app seems to start alright without any exceptions but I cannot access the Eureka console from browser on the port 8080. I get a 404.

I know that there are several examples of Eureka on Docker but none using gradle and traditional deployment.

Command I use to start a container: `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -e DOCKER_HOST="$(echo $DOCKER_HOST | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}')" xxx`

Docker engine 1.9 with Docker Machine on a Mac.

**Log Snippet**:

```
Adding replica node: http://192.168.99.107:8080/eureka/
2015-12-26 03:35:42.959  INFO 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] n.a.javaee.discovery.DiscoveryServer     : Started DiscoveryServer in 8.167 seconds (JVM running for 12.804)
```

**application.yml**:

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8080}

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: ${DOCKER_HOST:localhost}
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM abhijitsarkar/docker:tomcat8

ADD build/libs/*.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/discovery.war

CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

**DiscoveryServer**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServer.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DiscoveryServer.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the app is running. Your Dockerfile copies the war to "discovery.war" so I'd expect it to show up on /discovery (but you didn't really say what you tried and what wasn't working).

Comment: Darn, in traditional deployment, the context root changes to `discovery`. That was what I was missing. And I spent several hours looking into Docker networking options :(
Thank you Dr. Syer. On a separate note, it'd be nice to have the various Eureka and Config parameters listed someplace, like you've for boot. For config, I found some in `EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration` but digging through source code is tiresome.